# How to insert custom code on Collections List in the products Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm Building a custom collection page in shopify, I want to show some custom code between products it can be pictures or text.  How do I achieve that? can anyone help out?

Example with picture and the link here,  [image: https://www.mrporter.com/en-my/mens/designer/iwc-schaffhausen]

This is where I want to apply a similar layout. https://junghans.com.my/collections/best-selling-collection (Pass: 12345)

Comment: Need to check the liquid code and edit the loop where products are listed and append your custom code on desired page, by the way shared link is password protected.

Comment: Hi @Onkar, Thank you for your answer here, & apology for previously adding you as an answer, anyway, this is the website as a sample [Mr. Porter design to be similar](https://www.mrporter.com/en-my/mens/designer/iwc-schaffhausen).

[Junghans Malaysia Where need to apply the code ](https://junghans.com.my/collections/best-selling-collection). 
password: 12345